# Changing the elements of a matrix using a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I'm having a few issues getting MATLAB to do what I want.

say I have a matrix `x = [1 2 3 4; 1 4 4 5; 6 4 1 4]`

I'm trying to write code that will go through the matrix and change each 4 to a 5, so it modifies the input matrix

I've tried a few things:

```
while index <= numel(x)
    if index == 4
        index = 5;
    end
    index = index + 1;
end


for item = x
    if item == 4
        item = 5;
    end
end
```

the simplest thing i tried was

```
for item = x
    if item == 4
        item = 5;
    end
end
```

i noticed by looking at the workspace that the value of item did indeed change but the value of x (the matrix) stayed the same.

How do I get the output that i'm looking for?

Comment: +1 for showing what you have tried. Not knowing the answer is OK. Not attempting however, is not! Other than that, I highly recommend that you follow Dan's advice and avoid loops for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change all the `4`s to `5`s then:

```
x(x==4)=5
```

basically `x==4` will result in a logical matrix with `1`s everywhere there was  a `4` in `x`:

```
[0 0 0 1
 0 1 1 0
 0 1 0 1]
```

We then use [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to only affect the values of `x` where those `1`s are and change them all to `5`s.

If you wanted to do this using a loop (which I highly recommend against) then you can do this:

```
for index = 1:numel(x)
    if x(index) == 4
        x(index) = 5;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to achieve what you want:

```
x(x==4) = 5
```

Answer to why your code doesn't do what you expected:
You are changing the `item` to a 5. But that item is a new variable, it does not point to the same item in your matrix `x`. Hence the original matrix `x` remains unchanged.